# nextInt in java i don't understand how this works

Tags: java

I'm new to java and was viewing a tutorial and saw nextInt, the guy said that it was supposed to give me a number between -5 and 5 but i have two problems :

(r.nextInt(5 - -5) + -5)

1)In what order does it operate

2)The explanation that i found says that it doesn't accept negatives then why is it supposed to allow me to give me -5?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unary negative and subtration. Usually, that's written as `+`. Like

```
(r.nextInt(5 + 5) + -5)
```

which is

```
(r.nextInt(10) - 5)
```

I assume this is for a `Random`, in which case it returns `[0,10)`. Which if you subtract 5, is `[-5,5)`.

Comment: Oh i get it now so the -5 substracts from both minimum and the maximum not just from the maximum, thanks!

Comment: @Darkly It subtracts from the single value which is in the minimum to maximum range. Draw a number line from 0 to n, then move the origin point (*minimum*) left or right... to preserve the original line length you must move the end point (*maximum*) left or right by the same distance.

Answer (score 1):

What your code will do is generate a random integer between 0 and the specified value, and will then subtract 5 from the generated integer.